# Disable Bootstrap tooltips on xs screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, resize, tooltip

I am trying to disable tooltips in Booststrap on xs screens with this code:

```
function menuTooltip() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
        $('.menu a').tooltip();
    }
}
menuTooltip();
$(window).resize(menuTooltip);
```

Works fine except that if I resize the window it keeps showing tooltips on mobile devices. Seems like something is wrong with `$(window).resize(menuTooltip);` but I don't see anything. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I had to add `else { $('.menu a').tooltip('destroy') }` to make it work...